# Azure cosmos db issues with connection by resource token

Tags: permissions, azure-cosmosdb, resource-id, documentclient

I'm trying to connect to my `cosmos db` database by using a `Resource token` instead of a account `master key` which I used before.
Before I used the following way to create `DocumentClient`:

```
    var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(configAccountName), configAccountKey);
    await client.OpenAsync();
```

This way works well, but I want to use `resource token` ways for that target as mentioned in these articles : [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data) and [link2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/472).

I've created a `db user` with `All permissions` by the following code:

```
    public static async Task<User> CreateUserAndPermissionAsync(this DocumentClient client, string userId)
    {
        var dbUri = UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(dataBase);
        var user = await client.CreateUserAsync(dbUri, new User { Id = userId });
        var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(dataBase, collectionName);
        var permission = await client.CreatePermissionAsync(
            user.Resource.SelfLink,
            new Permission
            {
                Id = "MyPermission",
                PermissionMode = PermissionMode.All,
                ResourceLink = collectionUri.ToString(),
                ResourcePartitionKey = new PartitionKey(userId)
            });
        return user.Resource;
    }
```

The user is created correctly and I can retrieve him by `ReadUserAsync` or his permissions by `ReadPermissionAsync` methods.
Then, I want to create new instance of `DocumentClient` with `permissions` of newly created user.

```
    //this is a temporally document client instance to read permissions for my user in below extensions method versions
    var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(configAccountName), configAccountKey);
```

I've checked 3 ways (some of them are similar). I've tryied to call each of ways to get new `DocumentClient` instance(*newClient* variable) and then call `OpenAsync` method to open connection:

```
    var newClient = await client.GetClientForUserAsync_v###(userName);
    await newClient.OpenAsync();
```

All tryings were failed

```
    //version 1:
    public static async Task<DocumentClient> GetClientForUserAsync_v1(this DocumentClient client, string userId)
    {
        var userUri = UriFactory.CreateUserUri(dataBase, userId).ToString();
        var permissionsUri = $"{userUri}/permissions";
        var permissions = (await client.ReadPermissionFeedAsync(permissionsUri)).ToList();
        return new DocumentClient(
            client.ServiceEndpoint,
            permissions,
            client.ConnectionPolicy);
    }
```

The `OpenAsync` method was crashed with this error : *Failed to parse the value '' as ResourceId., documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.22.0 Host/32-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0*

```
    //version 2:
    public static async Task<DocumentClient> GetClientForUserAsync_v2(this DocumentClient client, string userId)
    {
        var userUri = UriFactory.CreateUserUri(dataBase, userId).ToString();
        var permissionsUri = $"{userUri}/permissions";
        var permissions = (await client.ReadPermissionFeedAsync(permissionsUri)).ToList();
        return new DocumentClient(
            client.ServiceEndpoint,
            permissions[0].Token,
            client.ConnectionPolicy);
    }
```

The `OpenAsync` method was crashed with this error : *Insufficient permissions provided in the authorization header for the corresponding request. Please retry with another authorization header.
ActivityId: ##ReplacedActivityId##, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.22.0.0, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.22.0 Host/32-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0*

```
    //version 3:
    public static async Task<DocumentClient> GetClientForUserAsync_v3(this DocumentClient client, string userId)
    {
        FeedResponse<Permission> permFeed = await client.ReadPermissionFeedAsync(UriFactory.CreateUserUri(dataBase, userId));
        List<Permission> permList = new List<Permission>();

        foreach (Permission perm in permFeed)
        {
            permList.Add(perm);
        }

        DocumentClient userClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(client.ServiceEndpoint.AbsoluteUri), permList, new ConnectionPolicy()
        {
            //**UPDATE**: I tried all ConnectionMode values as well as without this parameter
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway
        });
        return userClient;
    }
```

The `OpenAsync` method was crashed with this error : *Failed to parse the value '' as ResourceId., documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.22.0 Host/32-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0*.

The first and third errors are the most strange, because I've checked and I see the `ResourceId` value in the *perm* variable (as item of *permList* collection) as well as in *permissions* variable from the first version.

Could anyone help with it?

**UPDATE**
I've checked the 4th version, which gives me the same result as 1,3 trying: *Failed to parse the value '' as ResourceId., documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.22.0 Host/32-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0*

```
    //version 4
    public static async Task<DocumentClient> GetClientForUserAsync_v4(this DocumentClient client, string userId)
    {
        var user = await client.ReadUserAsync(UriFactory.CreateUserUri(dataBase, userId));
        var permissions = await client.ReadPermissionFeedAsync(user.Resource.SelfLink);
        List<Permission> permList = new List<Permission>();

        foreach (Permission perm in permissions)
        {
            permList.Add(perm);
        }

        DocumentClient userClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(client.ServiceEndpoint.AbsoluteUri), permList, new ConnectionPolicy()
        {
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct
        });
        return userClient;
    }
```

Comment: do you still have the same issue ?

Comment: @WalidAshraf, yep.

Comment: @dododo Have you found any resolution for the above issue? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Darey, no :( But I don't work on this issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The Cosmos DB resource token will be generated when the permission been built. We can use resource token to connect to Cosmos DB like below:

```
var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endPointUri), resourceToken );
```

And we can get resource Token of the permission as below:

```
    public static async Task<Dictionary<PermissionMode, string>> GetPermissonTokens(DocumentClient client,string DatabaseId,string userId)
    {
        FeedResponse<Permission> permFeed =  await client.ReadPermissionFeedAsync(UriFactory.CreateUserUri(DatabaseId, userId));

        Dictionary<PermissionMode,string> permList = new Dictionary<PermissionMode, string>();

        foreach (Permission perm in permFeed)
        {

            permList.Add(perm.PermissionMode, perm.Token);
        }

        return permList;
    }
```

Here is a Complete demo for your reference:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //create DocumentClient instance with end point Uri and primary key
        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://xxxx.xxxxx.azure.com:443/"), "ikhSrMZIGKBrF1xxxxx7iDSLBMJD37oCOlw2N24YoBtfAV7HJFfVgNbhCfQdWGAq3eZY4FyX3z6zsWoRLHQ==", new ConnectionPolicy { EnableEndpointDiscovery = false });

        Task<Dictionary<PermissionMode, string>> task = GetPermissonTokens(client, "Test2", "testUser2");
        task.Wait();
        Dictionary<PermissionMode, string> permissionTokens = task.Result;

        DocumentClient userClient = new DocumentClient(client.ReadEndpoint, permissionTokens[PermissionMode.All]);
        if (userClient != null)
        {
            //then we can do CRUD operation to Cosmos DB Here 
        }
    }


    public static async Task<Dictionary<PermissionMode, string>> GetPermissonTokens(DocumentClient client,string DatabaseId,string userId)
    {
        FeedResponse<Permission> permFeed =  await client.ReadPermissionFeedAsync(UriFactory.CreateUserUri(DatabaseId, userId));

        Dictionary<PermissionMode,string> permList = new Dictionary<PermissionMode, string>();

        foreach (Permission perm in permFeed)
        {

            permList.Add(perm.PermissionMode, perm.Token);
        }

        return permList;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Lee Liu, I've checked your solution and the result of **userClient.OpenAsync().Wait()** method is the same as in my **version 2**. I have the following error : *Insufficient permissions provided in the authorization header for the corresponding request. Please retry with another authorization header.
ActivityId: ##ReplacedActivityId##, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.22.0.0, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.22.0 Host/32-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0*.

Comment: Also, I would like to highlight that I use `Read and Write` `Primary key` from azure portal as **accountKey**. I didn't configure any other portal settings. Maybe I need to set some additional settings in Azure Cosmos db settings in azure portal?

Comment: @LeuLiu, just in case if previous way doesn't trigger notification

Answer (score 0):

I have similar case where in my model I am using partitioning. So, I have developed this function to be get the user token.

```
    private async Task<string> GetUserToken()
    {
        User user = null;
        try
        {
            try
            {
                var uri = UriFactory.CreateUserUri(config.Database, config.PartitionKey);
                client.DeleteUserAsync(uri).Wait();

                user = await client.ReadUserAsync(UriFactory.CreateUserUri(config.Database, config.PartitionKey));

                var permission = await GetorCreatePermission(user, config.Collection, config.PartitionKey);
                return permission.Token;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new User
                {
                    Id = config.PartitionKey
                };
                user = await client.CreateUserAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(config.Database), user);
                var permission = await GetorCreatePermission(user, config.Collection, config.PartitionKey);
                return permission.Token;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After multiple attempts, the one conclusion I ended up was not to include the PartitionKey when creating permission for the collection. The below tweak did the job for me and I am able to successfully add contents to my collection using resource tokens.

```
    new Permission
    {
        Id = "MyPermission",
        PermissionMode = PermissionMode.All,
        ResourceLink = collectionUri.ToString()
    });
```